# insert date null value using mysql real escape string

Tags: php, mysql

how to insert null date mysql real scape string

```
if (empty($DATE_PURCHASED)) {
    $DATE_PURCHASED = NULL;
} 

//sql query
$queryString = sprintf("INSERT INTO IT_ASSET_RADIO (BRAND_NAME, SERIAL_NO, DATE_PURCHASED, LICENSE_NO) 
    values ('%s','%s', '%s', '%s')",
    mysql_real_escape_string($BRAND_NAME),
    mysql_real_escape_string($SERIAL_NO),
    mysql_real_escape_string($DATE_PURCHASED),
    mysql_real_escape_string($LICENSE_NO));

$query = mysql_query($queryString ) or die("Insert failed: " . mysql_error());
```

> I got an error of this query invalid date in DATE_PURCHASED if value
>   is null

Comment: Your DB field is surely a "date" field, so you can't just insert NULL in it

Comment: @WaqasShahid Sure you can, as long as it's nullable.

Comment: Instead of NULL, it can insert "0000-00-00"

Comment: really? I haven't experienced it

Comment: You can't insert NULL using an escape string function.  Especially the way you're doing it.  You're specifically declaring it as a string by encapsulating it in `'`, using escape string, and `%s`.  NULL is not a string.

Comment: so what's your alternative query if date field is null?

Comment: My alternative would be to stop using mysql_ and escape string functions, other than that, you'll have to think about this more logically of how to handle non-string values.

Comment: check the link given by @RobbyCornelissen. useful for you.

Comment: set DATE_PURCHASED column in table default NULL

Answer (score 1):

```
$date=mysql_real_escape_string($DATE_PURCHASED); 
if(trim($date)==''){ $date=NULL;}
```

use $date  in your query.

And also

set **DATE_PURCHASED** column in table **default NULL**

Comment: That won't work in strict mode, not sure about others.  If you specify an empty string, it will try to insert an empty string, not a NULL value.  Defaults are useful for when the column is excluded from the insert statement.

Comment: I already set the DATE_PURCHASED into null but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the date string in the format like 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS', do it like below:

```
..........mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($DATE_PURCHASED))).....
```

Comment: Woh! it doesnt return null.. XD

Comment: @json If this answer is useful to you then please accept it and up vote it, so other knows that, you got the solution. None other waste their time to find the solution.

Comment: @json It doesn't return null, but you got the diff error. You just have to check it before passing to the mysql query and if the variable is blank then set the variable blank and if they have any value then you have to pass it to DB with correct format.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($DATE_PURCHASED)) {      
      $DATE_PURCHASED = NULL;
    } else {
       $DATE_PURCHASED = $data->DATE_PURCHASED;
    }
    // Surround it in quotes if it isn't NULL.
    if ($DATE_PURCHASED === NULL) {
      // Make a string NULL with no extra quotes
      $DATE_PURCHASED = 'NULL';
    }
    // For non-null values, surround the existing value in quotes...
    else $DATE_PURCHASED = "'$DATE_PURCHASED'";

$queryString = sprintf("INSERT INTO IT_ASSET_RADIO (BRAND_NAME, SERIAL_NO, DATE_PURCHASED, LICENSE_NO) 
    values ('%s','%s', $DATE_PURCHASED , '%s')",
    mysql_real_escape_string($BRAND_NAME),
    mysql_real_escape_string($SERIAL_NO),
    mysql_real_escape_string($LICENSE_NO));

$query = mysql_query($queryString ) or die("Insert failed: " . mysql_error());
```

Comment: Solve my Problem! :D